# Searching for 12 separate strings with one function

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a macro that searches for a string ("January ") and converts the space to a protected space. What I'd like to do is search for the other months of the year as well. Is there a way of searching for the other months within the same function, rather than copy and paste my code 11 times, searching for a different month each time?

Here's my code so far after a couple of suggestions that have mostly worked but not quite and I can't figure out why:

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim months(1 To 12) As String
Dim str As String

    months(1) = "January ": months(2) = "February ": months(3) = "March ": months(4) = "April ": months(5) = "May ": months(6) = "June ": months(7) = "July ": months(8) = "August ": months(9) = "September ": months(10) = "October ": months(11) = "November ": months(12) = "December "

    For Each item In months
        Selection.Find.Execute item
        Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
            Selection.MoveRight.Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.TypeBackspace
            Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
            Selection.Find.Execute
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

I have a letter containing four dates in this order: October 2019, December 1974, November 2019, October 2019. I also added a list of 12 dates (various dates and years, but one for each month) at the end of the letter, to test it worked on every month, which it does.

In the body of the letter, only the two October 2019s work. When changing December 1974 to October 1974, that one works, but the first October 2019 doesn't. When changing them to this order: September 2019, October 1974, November 2019, December 2019, they all work. When changing them to December 2019, November 1974, October 2019, September 2019, only September works.

Comment: What do you mean by "protected space"? A non-breaking space?

Comment: Yes (Ctrl + Shift + Space). We call them protected spaces in my workplace, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track in using an array to hold the months but you don't need to include the following space.

There is also no need to make things complicated as Find and Replace can do the job for you.

```
Sub FollowMonthWithNonBreakingSpace()

  Dim item As Variant
  Dim months(1 To 12) As String

  months(1) = "January": months(2) = "February": months(3) = "March": months(4) = "April": _
  months(5) = "May": months(6) = "June": months(7) = "July": months(8) = "August": _
  months(9) = "September": months(10) = "October": months(11) = "November": months(12) = "December"

  For Each item In months
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .Text = item & " "
      .Replacement.Text = item & "^s"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! It worked on every instance of a month! Thank you! I had no idea you could do item & " ", that's a game-changer

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to make your posted code do anything. Please test the code below to see if it does what you need:

```
Sub MonthNamesToSpaces()
  Dim Months$(0 To 11)
  Months(0) = "January ": Months(1) = "February ": Months(2) = "March ": Months(3) = "April ": Months(4) = "May ": Months(5) = "June ": Months(6) = "July ": Months(7) = "August ": Months(8) = "September ": Months(9) = "October ": Months(10) = "November ": Months(11) = "December "
  For X = 0 To 11
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .Text = Months$(X)
      .Replacement.Text = " "
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next X
End Sub
```

Using the **Range** object instead of *Selection* makes for faster, more reliable code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want to replace the month with a space, I want to replace the normal space following the month with a protected space, so I changed the ".Replacement.Text"-".Execute" to Selection.MoveRight once, TypeBackspace once, TypeText " " and Execute, using Selection as it didn't like when I used Range. The result of this was it deleted 12 characters where the cursor was and inserted 12 protected spaces.

Comment: "converts the space to a protected space" was your text that looked like you needed a space. What is a "protected space"? That phrase is not used in Word or VBA. As I menitoned, you should use Range instead of Selection, as both Timothy and I have done.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Find is stopping when it reaches the end of your document. If that's the case you can (1) move the cursor to the top of the document before Find/Replace, and (2) set

```
Find.Wrap=wdFindContinue
```

so that Find wraps around when it reached the end of the document.

Comment: Cursor is already at the beginning of the document. Unsure where to place the FindContinue, but I put it just before Loop. Ran the macro on a different document with these dates in this order: 28 October 2019, 22 May 2005, 15 November 2019, and it skipped October and worked only on May and November. Also moving the cursor to elsewhere in the document (e.g. just before May) returned the same result.